# Is there any way to make this typified method generic?

Tags: java, function, generics, typed

I'm trying to write a method which takes any collection of any type, two functions and two integer values which represent a certain limit.

For a better understanding i will show an example method which i would like to build generic.

```
private void buildSums() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (YearlyLineValuesEntity y_l_v_E : yearlyList) {
        if (y_l_v_E.getDb() >= 20001 && y_l_v_E.getDb() <= 20155) {
            sum += y_l_v_E.getAmount();
        }
    }
}
```

The return value in the example method is not important in this case. Only serves for a basic understanding of what my goal is.

**This is my attempt:**

The numbers in the if statement above are represent by the parameters "from" and "to" in the following method i´ve tried. getDb() should come from the parameter "propertyDb" and getAmount() should come from "propertyAmount"-paramater.

```
    <T> List <Double> sumUpGroup(Collection<? extends T> entityList, Function<? super T, Integer> propertyDb, Function<?
        super T, Double> propertyAmount, int from, int to) {
    Double sum = null;
    List<Double> list = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
        EntityList x = entityList.get(i); //generic type
        if (x.getDB() >= from && x.getDB() <= to) { //propertyDb here
            sum += x.getAmount(); //propertyAmount here
        }
    }
    list.add(sum);
    return list;
}
```

I don't know how to proceed further in the code with the 2 functions that come as parameters in the method. Do I need another method to take care of this?

do any of you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: So you want to provide accessors? Such as `sum += propertyAmount.apply(x);`? Your `sum` can't be `T` obviously, it should be `double` and you should return `List<Double>` instead of `List<T>` since `T` is reserved for your entity type.

Comment: Yeah..right, changed the return value..

Comment: "So you want to provide accessors? Such as sum += propertyAmount.apply(x);?" Yeah i think so :)

Comment: EntityList.get(i) can only return `Object` in this case.  You don't know the type.  Also `.get(...)` is not supported on `Collection`.

Comment: If you want to use accessors from the entities, then they should all be of some interface. It's not clear exactly what you want to do with the functions, but I assume the function should accept the same interface and do something on it, and you use apply. You don't actually need a generic method here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I meant accessor functions. There's no need for interfaces. The collection can be iterated with a for-each loop.

Comment: OK, then. Why aren't you using the `Function`'s `apply` method then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following would work (I removed the list stuff for clarity)

```
<T> double sumUpGroup(Collection<? extends T> entityList, 
    Function<? super T, Integer> dbAccessor, 
    Function<? super T, Double> amountAccessor, 
    int from, int to) {

    double sum = 0;
    for (T entity : entityList) {
        int value = dbAccessor.apply(entity);
        if (value >= from && value <= to) {
            sum += amountAccessor.apply(entity);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

You cand then call the method as follows, with the correct method names given of course

```
sumUpGroup(myEntities, Entity::getDbValue, Entity::getAmount, 0, 100);
```

Comment: I would use [ToIntFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) and [ToDoubleFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToDoubleFunction.html) for the argument types, to eliminate boxing and unboxing.

Comment: Works very well, Thanks! :)